# Getting a Uncaught ReferenceError for an array i thought i defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: answers is not defined"  The problem is that i thought i defined the variable.

**summary of my code.**

I have a class that turns on, on click, then another function that maps those answers and puts it into the array answers.

im then using ajax to send the name entered into the form and the array i just made to a php doc. the array is the part thats giving me trouble

[live version on the site](http://tdring.com/ramen/)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdring/ku9pwo4c/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  //catch this values, because you will use these for more than one time
  var answers = [];



  function getAnswers() {
      answers = []; //empty old answers so you can update it
      $.map($('.on'), function(item) {
        answers.push($(item).data('value'));
      });
    }
    //init the answers in case you use it before click
  getAnswers();


  $(document).on('click', 'img', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('on');

    //trigger the state change when you click on an image
    $(document).trigger('state-change');
  });

  //get answers when event was triggered
  $(document).on('state-change', function(e) {
    getAnswers();
  });

  $('#btn-show').click(function() {
    alert(answers.join(',') || 'nothing was selected');
  });



});
//ajax to send the data to php file
$(document).on('click', '#btn-show', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ".../inc/insert.php", //"/path/to/script.php"
    data: {
      "name": $('input[name="name"]').val(),
      "choices": answers
        //this is the part giving me an error
    },
    success: function(response) {
      alert(response);
      //the response variable contains whatever your PHP echoes out --
    }

  });

});
```

```css
/* style for the selectable images  */

.choices {
  margin: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
/* this shows the user which item has been selecting along with making a searchable class for the program */

.on {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
  <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/code.css" TYPE="text/css">

  <!DOCTYPE HTML>

  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript.js"></script>
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/code.css" TYPE="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post">
      Name
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <br>
      <img src="img/m_bacon.jpg" alt="Bacon" class="choices" data-value="0">
      <br>
      <img src="img/m_beef.jpg" alt="Beef" class="choices" data-value="1">
      <br>

      <button id="btn-show">Submit</button>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope issue. Notice that you declare `var answers = []` in the `$(document).ready(function () {...}` function, but your click event is outside that `ready` function.

Also here is the edited version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ku9pwo4c/1/ (Note that it won't work on JS Fiddle due to the AJAX request url, but if you paste it, it should work assuming your PHP endpoint works correctly.)

Here is a a simplified example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var answers = [];
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn-show', function () {
    // This will be undefined because answers was declared in a 
    // different function scope.
    console.log(answers);
});
```

A possible fix is to move your click event handler inside the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var answers = [];
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-show', function () {
        // This time answers will be `[]`
        console.log(answers);
    });
});
```

---

I also added a snippet of the working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var answers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  $(document).on('click', '#btn-show', function () {
    console.log(answers);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-show">Click me!</button>
```